# Why curves not plotted by splited arange in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, range, curve

This code is ok in matlab but in python it does not worked and not plotted curves that calculated for `r=(ri/1000, ri/100, ri/10)` Actually it just plotted last values.
How can I plot curves for all `ri` values? I dont want to use `for`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(263, 383, 0.001) 
ri = np.arange(1,9)
r = (ri/1000, ri/100, ri/10, ri)

T, R = np.meshgrid(t, r)
k1=np.exp(17.34-(48900./(8.314*T)))
k2=np.exp(42.02-(124200./(8.314*T)))
XA=(k1-R)/(k1+k2)

plt.contour(T,XA,R)
plt.axis([263,383,0,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tracked the type and shape of all variables?  Don't make assumptions based on matlab experience. Test, verify, etc.

Comment: See [How to find and connect the maximum points from each contour line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67952913/7758804), which appears to be the same code.

Comment: Yes I saw this thank you, but my question is difference...my problem is defining range to plot 28 curves from 0.001 to 9 without `for` ! This code just plot 7 curves which seems to be true but does not plot completley, I dont know where I went wrong!

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, maybe `r=(ri/1000, ri/100, ri/10, ri)` is not true but how can I plot curves in this range?